# Commuting squares in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Here $A,B,C$ and $D$  are all objects in an **Abelian category**.

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @> >> B @> >> C;\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
D @> >>E @> >> F;
\end{CD}
$

The square $ABCDEF$ commutes (the outer square ) and the square $BEFC$ also commutes. Is it true that the square $ADBE$ commutes? If so why?

Comment: Well, I was trying to prove that Sheaves on abelian categories are abelian. While proving that I'm getting this problem. (existence of products and kernels)

Comment: I don't think that you need this.

Comment: yeah, I don't need this. I got the proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $F=0$, the hypotheses hold trivially, and there is no reason for the conclusion to hold.